# "integrationuser" is not an Active user in KissFlow

Tags: kissflow

I am using [kissflow](https://help.kissflow.com/tips-and-tricks/api-documentation/attachment-creation-and-deletion-api) API to attach file but I am getting this error

> {
>       "error": "ValidationError The user integrationuser@xxxxxxx is not an
>   Active user" }

I am using this url with data `{Name:'xxxxx','Url':'xxxxxx'}` as suggested in Doc

```
https://sxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/api/1/Print Quotation/Sxxxxxx9/attachment/create
```

I already created request for this with this url

```
http://sxxxxxxxxx8.appspot.com/api/1/PrintQuotation/create
```

And got success result with `id` and `subject`

```
{
  .......
  Id": "d442c98a-bca2-11e8-9ac6-c7734a25d32a",
  "Subject": "Request from integrationuser@ap9d9afe30_96bd_11e8_a251_0e8f5e2360a0"
}
```

Please help me to understand why this error comes.

Note : I am using test account.
And there is no such user with name `integrationuser` in `Users`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, in my case im using a real account.

SOLUTION 1 :

1. Create a valid account for use in integrations e.g. integration@companydomain.com
2. Add the header "email_id" with the email of this user "integration@companydomain.com"

It works for me with a valid account.

However i need to pay by a license for it =P.

I'm talking with support for a better solution using default integrationuser, i will post here the answer from support for clarify this situation.

You can see this solution on documentation here :

https://help.kissflow.com/tips-and-tricks/api-documentation/rest-api-points

[image: Example using Postman]